# R add many columns by a function

Tags: r

I am trying to cut a number in layers by mean the next code:

```
X <- matrix(c(6,7,9,9,9,17,19,4,12,2,3,6,7,7),ncol=2)
layers <- c(5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40)
partitions <- function(u) {cbind(pmin(layers[1],u),t(diff(pmin(layers,u))))}
X <- cbind(X,lapply(X[,2], partitions))
```

The function returns an integer partitioned in the layers.

> A = a1 + a2 + .... + a8

Example

```
A <- 19
partitions(A)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8]
[1,]    5    5    5    4    0    0    0    0
```

But the results does not have the matrix I need. The final matrix would be of 7 x (2 (cols from X) + 8 (num of layers in points))

```
     [,1] [,2]      [,3]
[1,] 6    Numeric,8 NULL
[2,] 7    Numeric,8 NULL
[3,] 9    Numeric,8 NULL
[4,] 9    Numeric,8 NULL
[5,] 9    Numeric,8 NULL
[6,] 17   Numeric,8 NULL
[7,] 19   Numeric,8 NULL
> dim(X)
[1] 7 3
```

I tried different forms and ever had errors of dimensions.

Regards

Comment: Would you mind to add the structure of `points`

Comment: And you define `layers` and then never use it. (actually you *don't* define layers because you have a double `<-` - a typo perhaps?)

Comment: @SimonO101 I saw that... probably `points` was in there... :-)

Comment: I corrected the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of these two should be what you want

```
> rbind(t(X),sapply(X[,2], partitions))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
 [1,]    6    7    9    9    9   17   19
 [2,]    4   12    2    3    6    7    7
 [3,]    4    5    2    3    5    5    5
 [4,]    0    5    0    0    1    2    2
 [5,]    0    2    0    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    0

> cbind(X,t(sapply(X[,2], partitions)))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    6    4    4    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[2,]    7   12    5    5    2    0    0    0    0     0
[3,]    9    2    2    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[4,]    9    3    3    0    0    0    0    0    0     0
[5,]    9    6    5    1    0    0    0    0    0     0
[6,]   17    7    5    2    0    0    0    0    0     0
[7,]   19    7    5    2    0    0    0    0    0     0
```

Comment: yes! The second is the answer. thanks a LOT.  
Do you have an explanation for my error? Because don t understand what i am thinking wrong

Comment: @CaptainTyler They, `lapply` and `sapply` are very similar, try to type just `sapply`. They differ a bit because the former return always a `list` and the latter try to simplify to `array` the result coming from `lapply`. Hope I was clear...